# mv: cannot stat

Tags: raspberry-pi, mv

I wrote a script to capture images from the Raspberry Pi NoIR cam. I want to timestamp the name of the image but I also need the name for another process. I tried:

```
# Define path
path="/home/pi/Pictures/project/"

# command to capture image in signal mode
raspistill -t 500 -s -w 1024 -h 768 -q 100 -n -awb off -awbg 1.01,0.73 \
    -o ${path}"tmp/tmp.jpg" &

...do other stuff

# capture image
pkill -SIGUSR1 raspistill

# create timestamp name
NAME=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")".jpg"
mv ${path}"tmp/tmp.jpg" $path$NAME
```

During the mv command I get a mv: cannot stat no such file or directory error. The directory does exist however no image seems to get saved so it appears my -o path has an error but I cannot figure out what it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Put an `echo` in front of the `mv` to see where the command parameters are messed up.

Comment: `mv ${path}"tmp/tmp.jpg" $path$NAME` is quote deficient. You should be doing it as: `mv "${path}tmp/tmp.jpg" "$path$NAME"`

Comment: Hi guys, I tried both of your suggestions, echoing the mv command shows a valid path. Also placing the quotes around everything didn't solve the issue either. I'm not sure if either of you are familiar with raspistill, however I have a feeling that the image isn't getting saved fast enough and as such the move command doesn't see the file tmp.jpg because it does not exist yet. Can this be the case? If so how would you approach fixing this?